# Two applications communicating in same server: localhost vs server ip address

Tags: web-applications, server, localhost, ip-address

I have two applications communicating each other in same server. Every thing works fine in windows irrespective of whether i put 'localhost' or 'ip address' in http call. But in linux only putting 'localhost' works fine but not 'ip address'.

Am confused why so?.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more? Like the IP address you were using. Were you using something like 127.0.0.1 as the IP instead of localhost? Because 127.0.0.1 is not always equivalent to localhost. Localhost is protocol independent, IPv4 and IPv6 will work. But the IP will be slightly different for these.

Comment: many possible reasons. network configuration, firewall configuration, service port settings...

Comment: @Shrikant, We are using local ip like 192.168.1.1 .

Comment: @Tuncay, are all http request going to hit network card before hitting application server if we use ip address explicitly instead of localhost ?, i guess firewall comes into picture in this scenario.

Comment: As I said, there can be many many reasons. Even as basic as does the host have that IP address ? Does the server process listen on that interface on specified port ? Is that interface even up ? Normally firewalls don't block local connections, but it is possible...  You need to check your configuration, this isn't something we can answer here.